# Unable to locate element using this XPath

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is my xpath - `//*[@id="284623"]/div[4]/div[4]/img`

Unable to locate element using above XPath.

Please help..!

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: What are you trying to find it with? For what purpose? What error are you getting?

Comment: It's better to add detail info about your exact problem. Add your HTML code to locate this particular element.

Answer (score 1):

I have three answers for you.

1. You could open the source code and fine an element which matches the
   XPath, which from the information you have given will be structured
   like this:

   ```
   <? id="284623">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div></div>
     <div><img></div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Or You can open the dev tools in Chrome (F12) and in the console
   view and type in:

   ```
   $x("//*[@id='284623']/div[4]/div[4]/img")
   ```

   When you expand out the tree it should highlight the object on the
   screen for you.
3. Alternatively you can take a couple of hours to read through through
   the [W3 School XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) which will explain how the syntax
   navigates the tree structure.

Comment: How is your answer related to selenium-webdriver?

Comment: Which language are you using?